# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Desktop 64 bit user permissions or apache2 rewrite problem

Tags: 12.04, apache2, lts, phpmyadmin

I have installed 12.04 Desktop 64 bit, manually installed LAMP, phpmyadmin, php5-dev, PEAR, PECL, apc, ssh, created user to own `/var/www/` and transferred 3 sites to `/www/`. The sites are in subfolders, sites - available all configured, and enabled.

One site is pure html, two others - php. Enabled curl, but phpmyadmin started at first, also php sites, then stopped working.  /show blank pages/ sites said Clean urls cannot be enabled. Html site still working.

Where is the problem, and why the php sites stop working?

In all apache .conf files Allow Override is set to ALL. php sites have .htaccess files. And this configuration worked with Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the php 5 configurations?

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf
```

Conflicting security issues? Mod-rewrite issue, maybe? My 2 cents. Hope it helps.